# PHP cURL HTTP Code 0 in Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl, youtube

I am using curl in the Google App Engine (GAE) environment. My code simplified is as follows

```
$url = 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/rzuYnQwD840/0.jpg';
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($handle);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

As long as `$url` is valid, one would expect `$httpCode` to be 200. This is what I get testing this code locally. This code was also working last month on GAE in production last month when it was pushed. Today we noticed that `$httpCode` is now coming up as 0 on GAE. Is there some way to fix this? I just need to test if the response to a URL request is 200.

**Update:** It looks like the issue is limited to YouTube? There doesn't appear to be a problem with Vimeo (e.g. `$url = https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/149497499.json';`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer I was looking for in another GAE question ([PHP's Curl not working on AppEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789592/phps-curl-not-working-on-appengine)). Within the `php.ini` file in the base directory of the application, add the following:

```
google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"
```

I'm using Apache for local development, but if you're using GAE locally then add the following

```
extension = "curl.so"
```

**NB** You can only have one of these in you `php.ini` file at a time. It will ignore whichever one comes second.

Answer (score 0):

**First Method:**

Replace $url with 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/rzuYnQwD840/0.jpg';

This problem occurs due to SSL. You are hitting a secure URL.

**Second Method:**

Use the following code:

```
$url = 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/rzuYnQwD840/0.jpg';
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($handle);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Comment: SSL doesn't appear to be the issue. See the update to my question - a Vimeo https request works just fine.

Comment: Ever hopeful, I tried this on GAE anyway - doesn't work. Did you test this or just guess?

Comment: Yes, I have tested this. I think, you website is not has the SSL certificate. Please add following line while make the request:  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0) .